# What is the type for Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1))?

Tags: dart

I added an "always_specify_type" to my lint check, it is asking me to enter the type for:

`await Future<???>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));`
What should this type be and why? Should it be Void or Null or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `void` since you have no intention of actually using the value returned from the `Future`. By doing so, you will get a compile error if you are ending up trying to use the returned value by accident.